# Should(n't?) the tags for TFS tags be more dashing?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

A minor thing, but we like things clean, right?

For most tags about products with major versions, at least for Microsoft products, a dash is included in the tag name. For example:

- [visual-studio-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015) [visual-studio-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013) etc
- [sql-server-2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2014) [sql-server-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) etc

But for TFS the tags are:

- [tfs2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs2005) [tfs2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs2008) [tfs2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs2010) [tfs2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs2012) [tfs2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs2013) [tfs2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs2015), [tfs2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs2017) and the odd one out [tfs11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs11)

I have no rep there to suggest synonyms, let alone renaming tags (is that even possible?).

What do you think? Add some dashing magic? If no, help me understand why. If yes, help me understand how!

Comment: At least `tfs2012` and `tsf11` should be made synonym, `tfs2012` description explicitely says "The actual version number of the product is 11, so TFS 11 and TFS 2012 are actually the same thing.".

Comment: You're a little CDO like me... I like it... :)

Comment: Nevermind, I guess it's a thing... hWy opst eehrt, ghhotu?  hWy not eirtw eeghinrtvy in aaabcehillpt deorr?

Comment: @J... Just..... no... stop

Comment: @J... aBceesu aaagmnrs: "stop" adn "post".

Comment: @tepples Intelligibility? What's that got to do with it?  Really, I'm just bitter that my previous joke backfired on account of ignorance of the whole CDO a̶f̶f̶e̶c̶t̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶  meme...

Comment: dashifying seems like the right solution.

Comment: Grasping at a rationale after the fact: could be that in the case of TFS, "TFS2015" would be an acronym, for "Team Foundation Server 2015." Thus, not separate words. (More prosaically, whoever started the first tag was used to the acronym being all together, and everyone else just followed their lead.) I'm not actually in favour for or against either.

Comment: to be really aligned to the rest shouldn't it be team-foundation-server-20XY ?